# Move from point a to point b as quick as possible

Tags: calculus

I would greatly appreciate help with this assignment problem:

I am currently standing in point $(2,0)$, and must move to point $(-2,0)$ as quick as possible. There lies a swamp in $ |x|+|y| ≤ 1 $.

Outside the swamp my speed is $ v = 5 $.

Inside the swamp my speed is $ v = \frac{5\sqrt5}{2\sqrt2} $

At what point will I go into the swamp? Or is it better, given that I need to get to point $(-2,0)$ as quick as possible, to go around?

Comment: You can spend $0$ time in it if you don't enter it and just go around the swamp altogether. That's certainly the minimum. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @MPW Undid an edit from another user, and edited myself. Is it clearer now?

Comment: That’s a very thin swamp. Did you mean $\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert\le1$?

Comment: @amd yes:))) Thanks. Fixed. - Actually, no. Yes, it's a thin swamp. But it says "in" $||+||≤1$ though.

Comment: If so, then the presence of the swamp is almost entirely irrelevant to the problem. No matter what path you take, unless it follows any of the four line segments that $\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert=1$ consists of, you will spend zero time in the swamp. The straight line between the two points then gives you the minimal travel time. That’s quite obviously _not_ what’s meant in this exercise.

Comment: @amd Might be a translation/wording thing. For example, is "inside" $||+||=1$, the same as $||+||≤1$ ? That's what I meant by "in" $||+||=1$. But, you're right. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you go into the swamp at height $h$. If you get $|h|\ge 1$, you just go around it.

The distance from $(0,h)$ to $(0,1)$ is $1-h$. Then the distance traveled through the swamp is $$d_S=2(1-h)$$
You enter the swamp at height $h$,and coordinate along $x$ axis $1-h$. Then the distance traveled outside is $$d_O=2\sqrt{h^2+(2-(1-h))^2}$$
The time traveled is $$t=\frac{d_O}{v_O}+\frac{d_S}{v_S}$$
If you take the derivative with respect to $h$, and set it to $0$, you get $$h=\pm \frac 12$$

Comment: Can you be a little more wordy about how you got the distance traveled outside? :)) And thanks for the help!!

Comment: Sure. The swamp is a square tilted at $45^\circ$. Due to symmetry of the problem, one moves along positive $y$ (or negative) outside the swamp, then parallel to $x$ axis in the swamp, then towards negative $y$ outside. The problem is symmetric with respect to $y$ axis. Then I need to look only at positive $x$, and just multiply by $2$. On the edge of the swamp, at $y=h$ you get $x=1-h$. So you travel outside from $(2,0)$ to $(1-h,h)$. So the distance is given by the Pythagoras' theorem $d_O^2=\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2=[2-(1-h)]^2+(0-y)^2]$.

Answer (score 0):

The swamp is a square of side $\sqrt 2$ tilted at $45^\circ$ and centered on the origin.  One approach is just to follow the $x$ axis, so compute the time that takes.  One approach is to avoid the swamp by going from $(2,0)$ to $(0,1)$ to $(-2,0)$, so compute the time that takes.  The third is to go from $(2,0)$ to some point $(x,1-x)$ outside the swamp go to $(-x,1-x)$ inside the swamp, and then to $(-2,0)$.  Compute the time that takes, minimize by taking a derivative with respect to $x$ and setting to zero...